# Dynatree onDragOver and onDrop work perfectly in IE9, but only intermittently in Chrome

Tags: dynatree

I am trying to implement the drag and drop funcationality with the Dynatree plugin.  It works completely as expected in IE 9.  In Chrome, however, the functionality is intermittent.  I have downloaded the latest .js files from the Dynatree web site, and also played around with the versions of jquery.js that I am referencing.

At first, I thought that in Chrome the onDragOver and onDrop functions that I had declared were simply not getting called.  However, when I inserted console log statements, then launched the MVC project in which the Dynatree object was being rendered, I could see in the Chrome developer tools console monitor that the onDragStart function was always called without fail, but when I would drag the mouse around with the "attached" node, I could only get the onDragOver function to fire in what seemed like random spots.  When I got the onDragOver to fire and actually "reference" or highlight one of the other nodes in the tree, the onDrop function would also work.

Ironically, this code below works perfectly in IE9.  I can get it to work in Chrome, but only if I use it in a WebForms ASP.NET project.  Now, I'm sure you're thinking, "Why not just use it in a WebForms project?".  That remains a possibility (last resort), but with what we need to accomplish with saving changes to our database, the MVC will work much better for the other aspects of the site.  The code below fairly closely follows one of the examples provided on the Dynatree home website.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Update:  I have discovered that it isn't that the onDragOver and onDrop functions are not being called.  When viewed in Chrome using MVC, the dynatree is just very picky and sensitve to exactly where you click.  This could entirely be a product of my json string, or some settings on Chrome.  I just don't know yet.  If I click to the left of the node, I can select it every time, and move it to where I want.  I have to be very specific with where I drag it and drop it.  In Chrome, in the web forms model, it seems as though the "areas" within which you can operate are simply much larger.  ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OrgTree").dynatree({
        initAjax: {
            url: $('#Path').val()
        },
        dnd: {
            onDragStart: function (node) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dragging for the tree.
                *  Return false to cancel dragging of node.          
                */
                //alert(node);
                logMsg("tree.onDragStart(%o)", node);
                return true;
            },
            onDragOver: function (node, sourceNode, hitMode) {
                /** Return false to disallow dropping this node.          *          */
                logMsg("tree.onDragOver(%o, %o, %o)", node, sourceNode, hitMode);
                // Prevent dropping a parent below it's own child         
                if (node.isDescendantOf(sourceNode)) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Prohibit creating children in non-folders (only sorting allowed)
                //if (!node.data.isFolder && hitMode === "over") { return "after"; }
            },
            onDrop: function (node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dropping of items on
                *  the tree.          
                */
                logMsg("tree.onDrop(%o, %o, %o)", node, sourceNode, hitMode);
                if (node.isDescendantOf(sourceNode)) {
                    return false;
                }
                //alert(node, sourceNode, hitMode);
                //sourceNode.expand();
                sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
            },
           onDragEnter: function (node, sourceNode) {
                /** sourceNode may be null for non-dynatree droppables.
                *  Return false to disallow dropping on node. In this case
                *  onDragOver and onDragLeave are not called.
                *  Return 'over', 'before, or 'after' to force a hitMode.
                *  Return ['before', 'after'] to restrict available hitModes.
                *  Any other return value will calc the hitMode from the cursor position. 
                */
                // Prevent dropping a parent below another parent (only sort         
                // nodes under the same parent)         

                // Allowing dropping *over* a node will create a child of that node
                if (node.isDescendantOf(sourceNode)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return ["before", "after", "over"];
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the issue lies with the references to icon files and an older version of the jquery library being used.  I'm still not sure why it wasn't an issue for IE, but was for chrome.

My theory on why the incorrect reference to the icon file was causing a problem was that when no icons were rendered on the Dynatree object, Chrome did not insert any "pixel address" on which to click.  I realize that is not the correct term, but it is my theory.  In IE, it did not seem to be a problem.

When I rendered the page after correcting the reference to the icon file, all worked as expected.